# React.js dialog component disappears yet remains in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I'm using a Dialog component from Material-UI which, for the most part, is working correctly. However, if I click away from the Dialog, the Dialog will disappear (as expected) but sometimes, it remains in the DOM with its opacity set to 0, and I can't click anything else since the Dialog is in the way. This is a small sample of my code:

```
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Get data for ReactTable
  }, []);

  return(
    <div>
      // Other components
      <Button color="white" onClick={() => setOpenDialog(true)}>
         Open Dialog
      </Button>
      // Other components
      <Dialog open={openDialog} maxWidth="md" onClose={() => setOpenDialog(false)}>
        // ReactTable and close button
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
```

This bug doesn't always occur which makes it tricky to debug. I've only been using React for about a month, but I'm wondering if it's a state problem, or maybe some sort of race condition. Any suggestions?

Edit: This also occurs when a DropzoneDialog appears, to upload a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this same issue, I found the answer:

Elsewhere in the app, `useEffect()` was stuck in a loop and running extremely frequently which slowed the app down, causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
  <Dialog className={openDialog ? "" : classes.displayNone} open={openDialog} maxWidth="md" onClose={() => setOpenDialog(false)}>
   // ReactTable and close button
  </Dialog>
```

where in the styles file you have:

```
  displayNone: {
    display: "none"
  }
```